# Case Standard Report Type

Tags: reporting, standard

Is there a way to see how the objects are related  in the 'Case' standard report type? For instance, is 'Case' the primary object, which is set to have one or more related Contacts? And is the 'Customer/BP' object related to the case or the the contact object? I would like to know how objects relate in various standard report types.